# When using iOS universal link how to identify the calling app?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have two apps A and B and I am using iOS universal link to open app B from app A.

I have successfully set up app B so that it can be opened by universal links, and

**This is how I open app B inside app A**:

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly : @YES};
    NSString *stringURL = @"my_url";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:options completionHandler:nil];
    }else{
         //handle error
    }
```

**App B opens and this method is called in AppDelegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler{
    return YES;
}
```

But it looks like it does not provide any information regarding the calling app(app A).
It would be great if I can get the bundle id, or name of the calling app so that I can properly identify the calling app.

Is there any way I can identify the calling app?

Comment: App A would need to provide some information about itself in the URL that it uses to open app B. Eg `appB://?from=appA` you then extract the query string in App B and look for the `from` value

Comment: I know you can do that, but some malicious app can send some malicious data to pretend itself being legit, right?

Comment: I guess so, but that is pretty much your only option. If you are creating both apps then you can use an application group to share data.  The sending app could include a value in the URL that it also saved in the shared data store. The receiving app can then validate that value